# how do i get a tar file from gitlab of a specific repository branch via REST API

Tags: git, gitlab, gitlab-7, gitlab-8

How do i get an tar file from gitlab of specific **branch or tag** of an repository.
As of now i using like this 
*https://gitlab.com/api/v3/projects/:id/repository/archive?access_token=xxxxx*
This url which is downloading tar file of master branch..

Is there is any API to get the **branch and tag content as a tar file**..

Thanks advance...